# parse the data on new line using join and /n not working

Tags: python-3.x

```
    Output=[]

for each in e:
    try:
        loaded_data = json.loads(each)
        if loaded_data["action"] == "BLOCKED":
            Output.append(each)

    except Exception as err:
        print(f"Problem with line:{str(err)}")
        break

Output = '\n'.join(Output)
```

I tried to the json data on new with join and \n but it not working , its appending the line on same line only

Comment: Please correct your code block formatting. Also, please remove all unnecessary code. Which line exactly throws the error? I cannot find the line which joins strings.

Comment: I have removed the join bcoz it was not working there was no error. Can u help what shall do to list to print each loaded_data on next line

Comment: Please provide some data for us, so we can reproduce the context. Also, please add the desired outcome and the `join` attempt of yours.

Comment: if i run above code its printing \n

Comment: sample data : "timestamp":1586660423646,"formatVersion":1
o/p : "timestamp":1586660423646,"formatVersion":1 /n "timestamp":1586660423646,"formatVersion":1

expected o/p: "timestamp":1586660423646,"formatVersion":1
"timestamp":1586660423646,"formatVersion":1

Comment: I did not vote on your question. The downvote is probably set because of too little information from your side. Please do not post any further information of your question as a comment but place it into your question.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by adding indent and seperator